# Unable to read folder or file apache tomcat 6

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat6

I have a folder which reads out a File object and determines is it a directory or a file. if it is a directory it keeps on going in till it finds a file.

The code runs very fine on my machine in apache tomcat server, where as on a remote machine where I have given all the rights (read/write/execute) to that folder.

Apache tomcat failed to read from that folder. Where as simple java code can read the same folder on remote machine.

This is what i get on remote server. I know it is matter of permissions but where should I start from

```
file.isDirectory() false
file.isFile() false
file.canRead() false
file.isHidden() false
file.exists() false
```

Comment: Have you compared the tomcat configuration between the two systems? The error from `catalina.out` would also be of interest.

Comment: I am also facing same issue.